# Uploading the subtitles along with the video in azure devops

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore8, azure-media-services

I am new to Sitecore where I have a requirement to show the subtitles with the Video. After uploading the video in azure media services, I am successfully able to generate the subtitles but I am no where able to find the option to upload because of recent changes in UI.

[image: subtitles]

Comment: How do you generate and upload vtt files?

Comment: Regarding uploading assets to azure media services, there are only two ways I know, one is uploading on the portal, and the second is uploading via SDK (such as [AMS Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer)).

Answer (score 0):

Akash - What are you trying to achieve by uploading the captions to the video?

Normally you would do that by providing the URL to the VTT file in storage directly. The VTT file could be in the Asset folder, or in a separate asset.

Most web player frameworks support side-car VTT files.  In our own AMP player you can set it in the advanced options Azure Media Player (azureedge.net) [AMP with track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7i71.png)
By clicking on the Add Tracks and adding the VTT URL to it I believe.

Comment: I want to show the captions when the video is uploaded.